# Unable to get the Folder count in HDFS using Java

Tags: java, hive

I have a HDFS folder path as below.

sampleFolder/b/c/file1.orc\n
sampleFolder/d/file2.orc\n
sampleFolder/d/file3.orc

I want to get the count of files and folder at HDFS path "sampleFolder".
Expected output should be 6 ( i.e., folder b, folder c, folder d, file1.orc, file2.orc, and file3.orc).
But always getting only file count and not the folder count.

I am trying below code, but I am always getting output as

File
FileCount: 3

sHiveFilePath - hdfs://10.1.1.1:8020/sampleFolder.

Can someone please guide?

```
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> ri = hdfs.listFiles(sHiveFilePath, true);
                    LocatedFileStatus current = null;
                    while (ri.hasNext()) {
                        current = ri.next();
                        if(current.isFile()) {
                            System.out.println("File");
                            System.out.println("FileCount: " + fileCount++);
                        }
                        if(current.isDir()){
                            System.out.println("Directory");
                            System.out.println("Dir Count: " + fileCount++);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You probably meant to recurse and add the count from the subfolders. You aren't doing that. Also, shouldn't `hdfs://10.1.1.1:8020/a` be `hdfs://10.1.1.1:8020/sampleFolder`? What does `hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://10.1.1.1:8020/a` show?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Yes "a" is "SampleFolder". I corrected it in original question.  I am doing recursive operation. In expression "hdfs.listFiles(sHiveFilePath, true);" true stands for recursive operation.  Please advise.

Comment: `listFiles` does not list folders, only files within folders. If you also want to list the folders use `listStatus` instead.